# I want to download F&O BhavCopy from the below link using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm
```

Here after entering the required details, I have tried many times to click on "GetData" button, but Selenium doesn't click on the button. I have tried Below lines of code to click on button but still got no luck.

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[src='/common/images/btn-get-data.gif'][type='image']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@src='/common/images/btn-get-data.gif' and @type='image']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"getdata-button").click()
```

Here is the element from which I am trying to click on the button,

```html
<input type="image" class="getdata-button" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" onclick="validateInput()">
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error? If not, what is the result you get and what is the result you expect? Element selectors look ok.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a small script for that and I see what you mean. Nothing happens after the click.
I analyzed the behavior and I see that the click happens but for some reason all the requests hang in `Pending` status.

[image]

So, after the click, a request `https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=fobhavzip&date=08-11-2022&section=FO` is sent but it doesn't return any data.  Nothing wrong with your code but I think they somehow detect a "bot" and stop processing all requests from this browser session. You cannot even refresh the page.